# ¿Por qué no me imprime toda la tabla en PHP pero si en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysqli

El resultado en php no me muestra todo el contenido de la tabla. Pero en la consola de phpMyAdmin si me muestra todo.

**Acá el código desde la consola de phpMyAdmin**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Acá el código que trato de enviar**

```
    <?php 

$conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pem");
$consultar = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM prueba");
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($consultar, MYSQLI_NUM);

echo "IMPRESIÓN SIN CICLOS"."<br>";
printf($resultado[0]."<br>");
printf($resultado[1]."<br>");
printf($resultado[2]."<br>");

echo "IMPRESION CON CICLO FOREACH"."<br>";
foreach ($resultado as $key) {
    printf($key)."<br>";
}

echo "<br><br>";
echo "IMPRESION CON CICLO FOR"."<br>";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($resultado); $i++){
    echo $resultado[$i]."<br>";
}

mysqli_close($conectar);
echo ("TODO REALIZADO EXITOSAMENTE");
```

**Y acá les dejo el resultado lo que me imprime en php**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo agregar que me di cuenta el hecho de que encuentra es un solo elemento en el array. Mi duda está en por que muestra un solo elemento en php pero si todos en la consola phpMyAdmin? Muchas gracias de ante mano.

**Pd: Acepto sugerencias para mejorar mi forma de escribir código.**

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! podrias decir que te trae un echo de $resultado.. pareceria haber solo un registro en eso que consultas..

Comment: Estas leyendo un solo registro de la tabla, para leerlos todos necesitas leer dentro de un bucle.

Comment: Correcto, según php hay un solo registro, probado con ciclos For y Foreach.  Pero en la tabla hay tres registros. Lo comprobé con la consola de la db. Borré la tabla y la volví a crear agregando nuevos registros y me sigue mostrando "en php" que hay un solo registro.

Comment: Listo, copiado, Muchisimas gracias por la correción. Estaré atento la próxima vez. Es mi primera vez acá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch_array itera sobre sí mismo, es un iterador, por lo cual el ciclo que estás haciendo te va a marcar siempre la misma fila.

El `$i` que vale `0` en realidad te está trayendo la columna 0 de esa fila, no la fila 0

como en la documentación vienen los ejemplos, puedes intentar con este.

```
while($row = $consultar->fetch_array())
{
    echo $row['nombreJuego'];

}
```

o también

```
while(row = mysqli_fetch_array($consultar))
{
    echo $row['nombreJuego'];
    echo $row[0]; //funciona con indice o nombre de la tabla

}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Resultó su solución.

Answer (score 1):

Muchisimas gracias Sr1871. Acá publico el código como lo dejé y el resultado por si sirve a alguien más.

```
<?php 

$conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pem");
$consultar = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM prueba");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consultar))
{
    echo $row['nombreJuego']."<br>";

}

mysqli_close($conectar);
echo ("TODO REALIZADO EXITOSAMENTE");
```

**El resultado en php**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: debes marcar como aceptada la respuesta del usuario que te resolvió la duda, así es como funciona el sitio

Comment: Jaja ok. Listo, ahí voy aprendiendo a usar el sitio.